# Fibonacci function with floats in x86 assembler

Tags: assembly, x86

I wrote this but it doesn't work (crashes with n>6):

```
section .data
    one: dq 1.0
    two: dq 2.0

        section .text
fib:
    call    print_float
    fld qword [two]
    fcomip
    ja  fin
    fld st0     ; copy arg
    fld qword [one]
    fsub
    call    fib     ; st0=fib(n-1), st1=arg
    fld st1
    fld qword [two]
    fsub
    call    fib     ; st0=fib(n-2), st1=fib(n-1), st2=arg
    fadd            ; st0=fib(n-2)+fib(n-1), st1=arg
    fstp    st1     ; st0=fib(n-2)+fib(n-1)
fin:
    ret
```

What am I doing wrong and/or how should I be doing this?

Note: I know there is an instruction to load `1.0`. I'm just doing it this way for consistency in order to minimize the subset of x86 I have to deal with.

Comment: Did you try single-stepping through the code in a debugger ?

Comment: @PaulR I'm just writing x86 asm in Notepad under Windows, compiling with NASM then linking with GCC in a MinGW shell. I have no idea about better Windows tools. What would you recommend?

Comment: I'm not a Windows user but I know that you can get gdb as part of Cygwin, and I'm sure there must be plenty of other Windows-specific debuggers to choose from too. If you're going to do any serious programming then you really are going to need to get to grips with a decent debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x87 FPU registers act like a stack, but there are only 8 of them; and between the entry to `fib`, and the first `call fib`, you're leaving an additional item on the FPU register stack.

You should use the FPU registers only as necessary for performing calculations -- use the main stack to store values across recursive calls.

Comment: Argh, so obvious. Thanks! :-)